# Multiple LIKE in SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-like

I wanted to search through multiple rows and obtain the row that contains a particular item.

The table in mySQL is setup so each id has a unique list (comma-delimited) of values per row.

Ex:

```
id | order
1  | 1,3,8,19,34,2,38
2  | 4,7,2,190,38
```

Now if I wanted to pull the row that contained just the number 19 how would I go about doing this?  The possibilities I could figure in the list with a LIKE condition would be:

```
19,     <-- 19 at the start of the list
,19     <-- 19 at the end of the list
,19,    <-- 19 inside the list
```

I tried the following and I cannot obtain any results, Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
WHERE order LIKE '19,%' OR '%,19%' OR '%,19%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: Note that the sentence "row that contained just the number 19" could be understood to mean only rows that has only the value 19 in the order-field, in which case neither of your two example rows would match. I understood it, based on the rest of your text, to mean "row that contains the number 19 and not any number that contains 19 as part of it, like 190". I hope this is correct, otherwise please fix your question.

Comment: Hey thank you for your suggestion, I will use the child table in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to solve your problem in a simpler way:

```
SELECT *
FROM categories
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('19', `order`)
LIMIT 0, 30
```

In general though you should try to design your database so that this type of operation is not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should not store values like this, you should use a child table with one row per item, this would make your current query that much easier to handle, and would allow for indexes to be used as well.

Having said that, what you want is this:

```
WHERE ',' + order + ',' LIKE '%,19,%'
```

By adding a comma in front of and after the list of values in the `order` field, you can query that field for the value you want with a comma on each side, and not have to deal with the special case of the value being the first or last value in the list.

With the query you listed, you could've made it work by realizing that `OR` doesn't give more arguments to the `LIKE` clause, it separates entirely different clauses, and thus rewritten the SQL like this:

```
WHERE order LIKE '19,%' OR order LIKE '%,19,%' OR order LIKE '%,19'
                           ---+------      ^     ----+-----       ^
                              |            |         |            |
                              +- add this -+---------+            +- removed
                                                                     percent
```

**Note** the missing comma in the second pattern there, which would match strings containing the value 19, and note the removed percentage character in the last ,which would allow it to match lists that ended with 19.